# Transfer(copy&paste) data from one tab to another with transpose in #vba

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, I'm new in VBA. Basically, I want to transfer data from one tab to another(within one doc) and paste them transposed.

The code I have here, allows me to move to the next row, after submitting data for the first person.

```
Sub Submit()

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim iRow As Integer
    'tranferring data between macro
    Set rngSource = Worksheets("Checklist").Range("b1:b5")

    'figuring out the empty row
    iRow = Worksheets("Central Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Central Tracker").Range("A" & iRow)
    rngSource.Copy Destination:=rngTarget.PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Basically, I want to add in the transposed paste option but I don't know how I can do that. I will really appreciate your support. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Transpose:=True`

```
 Dim rngSource As Range
 Dim rngTarget As Range
 Dim iRow As Integer
 'tranferring data between macro
 Set rngSource = Worksheets("Checklist").Range("b1:b5")

'figuring out the empty row
iRow = Worksheets("Central Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Central Tracker").Range("A" & iRow)
rngSource.Copy 
rngTarget.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Hi Dorian, Still doesn't work. On "Transpose", I'm getting a compile error: Syntax error.

Comment: @Cyizere I edited My answer please give a try. Waiting for your feedbacks

Comment: @Cyizere If this issue is solved May I ask you to accept this answer ? Click [here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)